# DBUnit with HSQLDB: String column too short

Tags: string, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb, dbunit

I have an entity with the following attribute

```
@Lob
@NotNull
private String myContent;
```

Now, in my production setup I use a `CLOB` for representation in the database since the content can be several thousands of chars. However, for unit tests an in-memory HSQLDB is used. During the unit test I get this error

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation
>   at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)

As far as my research revealed, the reason should be that DBUnit creates a 255 char column for the string, automatically. And in my case it is not long enough for the content I insert. So, what could I do about this?

Comment: Note that dBUnit doesn't generate the DDL, the JPA implementation does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR", length = 65535)
@Lob
@NotNull
private String myContent;
```

That should cause a larger column to be created.

Comment: Hmm, Ok, but that would mean I modify my entity only for tests sake. That's not a clean code...

Comment: It's cleaner than non-working tests, IMO. Also, if you don't like this use something like liquibase and flyway and don't use the JPA to manage your schema. That's the "clean" way to do it.

Comment: OK, I used `@Column(columnDefinition = "CLOB")` and it worked out